# Is parent a reserved word in Meteor v0.8.0?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am upgrading an app to Meteor v0.8.0 from 0.7.2.

I have documents in collections where another document is the parent.  So, those documents have a field named parent.

I am having strange issues rendering the record.

It is showing the parent field as [object Object] when rendered in a template.

When output to console the parent field is

`Component {guid: "882", isInited: true, templateInstance: Object, parent: Component, dom: DomRange…}`

This leads me to believe parent is a reserved word and you should be careful when using it.

Comment: what do you mean by "when rendered in a template"? can you show us the template?

Comment: The spacebars template.  So, `{{parent}}` from Document.parent renders `[object Object]`  To be specific the collection is Sections and the field is parent so the helper is returning `Sections.find()`  I also tested by passing parent to a helper with an each and console log'd it `{{testHelper parent}}` and the output is `Component {guid: "882", isInited: true, templateInstance: Object, parent: Component, dom: DomRange…}`  I then changed the field name and reference from parent to section as in `Sections.section` and the problem is no longer exhibited.

Comment: it looks like the parent is an object?

Comment: It looks like parent is an object, and apparently it's an UI component – which probably means that Spacebars overrode whatever data there was before. So yes, it might be a reserved word, or a bug.